# Is there a Poisson-Gamma-Gamma model?

Tags: poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, actuarial-science

An example to elucidate my problem: The total claim amount can be modelled by a Poisson-Gamma model as it is assumed that the events (e.g. accidents) are Poisson distributed and the claims are Gamma distributed. As a mind experiment I now assume that the events follow a Poisson-Gamma model. If I now include the claims in that model, how is it called? Is this a “(Poisson-Gamma)-Gamma model” ?

So far I did not find a compound distribution for this. Can anybody give me an hint?

Comment: $S$ is not integer-valued, so how is $\sum_{j=1}^S$ defined?

Comment: S is not integer-valued, so your setup is somewhat strange mathematically.

Comment: I apologise for the strange setup ... Each element of S (assume it is an event on a time scale or a point on the DNA) has an U-value.So the jth value of S has the jth of U. S follows Poisson-Gamma and U Gamma. Retry: Poisson-Gamma is a mixture between Poisson and Gamma. My intention was to formulate a mixture of Poisson-Gamma and Gamma. Obviously my formulation was wrong. I am sorry. But I hope my example helps to understand the problem I have. Thanks.

Comment: You should really edit your question in light of Stefan and Aniko's feedback.  That will also focus the attention on the non-mathematical part of your question (which I think is what it now boils down to?)

Comment: I boiled it down ...

Comment: @Hermann Norpois by Poisson-gamma, do you mean using Bayesian inference to find the posterior distribution of number of claims?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, I will try to formulate it mathematically. Then you can verify if this formulation is what you intended. $N$ is a random number of accidents,
$$ N \mid \Lambda \sim \mathcal{Pois}(\Lambda), $$
where the Poisson mean $\Lambda$ has a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). Then marginally, $N$ has a negative binomial distribution.

Then for each accident there is a random claim $S_i$, which are independent, and also with a gamma distribution. Then the total claim amount is 
$$
 S= \sum_i^N S_i
$$ which is a sum of a random number (with a negbin distribution) of independent gamma random variables. Such random sums in studied in for instance [this paper](http://www.astrj.com/Approximation-of-random-sums-of-random-variables-in-insurance,139,0,2.html) and elsewhere. Is this what you had in mind?